# Why isn't this wrapping as expected?

Tags: html, css

I'm sure this is something silly I'm missing.  Can anyone take a look at [this page](http://atasteofnewtown.com/View2.aspx) and tell me why BYOB section is showing up on the right and not right under the American section?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a clearing element below the <div class="tagPlaces"> for Breakfast:

```
<div class="tagPlaces">
    <h3><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TagListView_ctrl2_TagName">Breakfast</span></h3>

    remaining div content
</div>
<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

Comment: Rule of thumb: Don't add extra elements when you don't need to.

Comment: But the parent of tagPlaces has clearfix applied to it.  Shouldn't that do it, since I'm floating tagPlaces?

Comment: I believe it's because the clearfix would need to be applied to every tagPlaces container, not just the parent.  I tried doing that and had no luck with it.  

In my experience, an explicit clearing element is the most consistently displayed, especially by our "friends" in the IE browser family.

Comment: Well, as much as I didn't want to do this, it seemed to be the only solution (short of using tables) that worked in FF and IE.  Thanks, Pat.

Answer (score 5):

Due to the combination of:

- The bar group is floating
- There is room beside the bar group for the BYOB group
- The BYOB group is `clear: none` (the default)
- The group between 'bar' and 'BYOB' is shorter than 'bar', leaving space under it but beside 'bar'

Set `clear: left` on every third group after the first (1,4,7,10,etc)

Comment: Hmm... that seems to be it!  I'm just not quite sure why there is room for BYOB beside Bar?  I guess this is related to variable heights?  Because if I set height to 200px across all the groups, the problem goes away.  I'll take it, but I won't be happy about it!  :)

Comment: @Joel No. Every third: #1 (although you don't need to), #4, #7, etc.

Comment: @fallen888: Yes. Since Breakfast is shorter than Bar, there is space left beside Bar and under Breakfast.

Comment: Spoke too soon...  this is great in FF.  But in IE7, Casual section now hugs the right side, instead of following immediately after BYOB in the middle.

Comment: Same for IE6 and while I agree that less markup is definitely better, if you want IE support, you're stuck with the explicit clearing element.  I added it after every 3rd group and it displayed fine in FF, IE, Opera and Safari.

Comment: Though this didn't work in IE, I still feel that this is the ideal solution.  So I up-voted.  Thank, David.